# Remove last n elements of vector<int> in O(1) complexity C++?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, stdvector

I want to remove the last n elements of a vector of integers in constant time complexity O(1). This should be doable I think because only some arithmetic for the end pointer is needed. However, erase, resize, and remove all have O(n) complexity. What function is there to use?

Comment: `std::vector::resize()`?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: @PaulSanders It says it's linear in complexity

Comment: I think that only applies for non-primitive types, when `n` destructors would need to be called.  For `int`s, no destructors need to be called to it should be O(1).

Comment: @PaulSanders I see, I thought it applied to everything. Do you also happen to know if it is also O(1) for removing from front?

Comment: No it's not, as the vector has to shuffled one place to the left and that's linear complexity on the number of elements remaining in the vector.

Comment: @PaulSanders That's what I thought, but pop_front is O(1) complexity. So wouldn't it be O(1) as well for deleting from front?

Comment: There is no `std::vector::pop_front`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ standard (I believe) says that the cost of removing k items from the end of a `std::vector` must have time complexity O(k), but that's an *upper bound* on the amount of work done, not a lower bound.

The C++ compiler, when generating code for `std::vector<int>::erase`, can inspect the types and realize that there's no need to do any per-element work when removing `int`s; it can just adjust the logical size of the `std::vector` and call it a day. In fact, [it looks like g++, with optimization turned on, does just that](https://godbolt.org/z/WCshFW). The generated assembly here doesn't involve any loops and simply changes the size of the `std::vector`.

If you don't want to rely on the compiler to do this, another option would be to store your own separate size variable and then just "pretend" that you've removed items from the `std::vector` by never using them again. That takes time O(1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, I don’t think so. That requires you to shift items down to fill in the empty positions, which can’t take time O(1).

Comment: The vector type doesn’t have pop_front. Are you looking at deque or list?